# Adding elements to SVG on the fly, elements added to the HTML DOM but not rendered

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a *SVG* which contains *text* within a *rectangle*. I would like to change the text at some user interaction.

Most of the code I have come across does something like this: (*sample code is for adding a circle*)

```
var shape = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
shape.setAttribute("cx", 25);
shape.setAttribute("cy", 25);
shape.setAttribute("r",  20);
shape.setAttribute("fill", "green");
```

While I used:

```
function writeSVG() {
        clearSVG();
        var name = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
        var txtNode = '<text id="newTxt" x="300" y="300">' + name + '</text>';
        $('#svgElem').append(txtNode);
        $('#popUp').hide();
    }

//Removes all text from SVG rectangle
    function clearSVG() {
        $('#controls text').remove();
    }
```

and my *SVG* is written directly into the *HTML*

```
 <div id="controls">
        <svg id="svgElem" height="600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">    Sorry, your browser does not support SVG.
        <rect id="rectSVG" width="500" height="500" style="fill:#FFFFFF;stroke:black;stroke-width:2;" onclick="launchPopUp();" />
       <text id="defaultTxt" x="200" y="200">Click in here!</text>
       </svg>
    </div>
```

**NOTE**: I am using Safari 5.1

Comment: Bit off topic but if you are working with svg elements maybe you should try Raphael.js. Really good library.

Comment: @Bruno: I intend to get my hands dirty with "*pure*" SVG before I wipe it clean using Raphael. Just for the learning exp u knw.....

Comment: Good strategy. That is a wise thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are creating the `<text>` element puts it in to the wrong namespace. Creating a string and then parsing it via .append() will put the element into the HTML namespace, not the SVG one.

You must wrap your string in `<svg>` and `</svg>` before parsing, and then append the children of the resultant root node to your `<svg>` element in the DOM.

Comment: something like this: *'<svg><text id="newTxt" x="300" y="300">' + name + '</text></svg>'*

Comment: while speaking of namespaces, I tried something like *var svgID = document.getElementById('svgElem');* and it turns out to be undefined! Is it because the SVG element lies outside the HTML namespace(which is covered by *document*)??

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, no. And I can't reproduce that problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjW7p/)

Comment: For me *var svgID = document.getElemntById('svgElem')* is undefined!

Comment: Might be a Safari thing I suppose. Looks like SVG support in Safari is very new.